# Find why a question was removed

Tags: support, moderation

I want to find out why a question has been removed.

I [answered this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346499/bash-put-text-into-a-variable-without-needing-to-escape-characters/346504#346504)  yesterday, and a 200+K rep user improved my answer. Trying to view the question I now I get a message:

> This question was removed from Unix & Linux Stack Exchange for reasons of moderation

Is there a way of seeing the discussion as to why the question was removed?

I'm not interested in why it may have been removed, I'm interested in why it was actually removed.

I thought it was a decent question as I answered it, and would like to refine my understanding of what is a good question based upon the discussion when it was removed.

Comment: The OP deleted it. Apparently, it is their moronic MO.

Comment: @jasonwryan does you comment suggest that the OP has posted a Q, gotten As, and then deleted the Q, this time and other prior occasions? Is that allowed after an answer is posted?

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver That is what it looks like to me. The question was deleted by Community, which presumably means someone marked it as a dupe and the OP agreed with it.

Comment: @jasonwryan What happens, then to the rep the OP got, if any, from upvotes? In the wind, or kept anyway?

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver I don't know; I am pretty sketchy on the administrative details of the site (I may have the above wrong). A mod will likely provide an authoratitive answer in time.

Comment: @jasonwryan How did you find out that the OP deleted it as opposed to a moderator deleting it or another reason? Is a certain amount of rep required?

Comment: @TomHale Yes, I can see the deleted questions, and why they were deleted. You can read on the main meta how Community deletes questions.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver All rep changes, positive or negative, for both the OP and the people that answered, are undone.

Comment: @jasonwryan [When can't I delete my own post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) says that a question can't be deleted when it has an upvoted answer.  I got at least +35 for my answer so it was definitely upvoted... How was the deletion possible given this?

Comment: @TomHale I don't know (like I said, I don't pay attention to the administrative minutiae), but I *guess* it was because Stephané marked it as a dupe and he has gold for that tag.

Comment: @TomHale The OP is a well-known troll, he deletes his questions after receiving answers so that nobody else can benefit from them (at least that's what he claimed at some point).  Personally I'd speculate this is a new form of homework automation, and the OP wants to maintain plausible deniability...

Comment: I've raised the conflict at [Question deleted with upvoted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291423/question-deleted-with-upvoted-answer)

Comment: @SatoKatsura The first part, his claim, seems totally contrary to the mission of SE. The speculation seems like it ought to get him banned. Maybe it'll get mod attention.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Is there anything we could point a mod to (eg this claim)? I'm pretty sour about a +30 answer being deleted, and would gladly flag this.

Comment: What's going on is actually more complicated, this clown edits his posts to political nonsense, this triggers downvotes, and _then_ the post gets deleted.  Or something like that.  At least one of the mods is aware of the problem.  I have no idea what (if anything) is done about it.  Just like you, I'm on the receiving side of it all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a well known troll user who's been plaguing the SE network for years. He has been declared no longer welcome across the entire network. As a result, we (mods) delete his accounts whenever we see them. This time, I destroyed the account (as opposed to "deleting") which also caused the questions posted to be deleted. I hadn't realized one of them had received useful answers, so that was also deleted.

I have now undeleted the question since the answers are indeed useful. I always try to keep useful content even if posted in response to questions by less than useful users, but I messed this one up. Sorry!

Also, please note that the questions themselves are sometimes perfectly decent. In those cases, please do answer them. I normally<sup>1</sup> check before deleting an account and take care not to destroy useful content. So answer the question if it's worth answering, but also flag it for mod attention if it looks like it's our friendly troll. The troll account will be deleted but your answer can help anyone else who finds the question.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Um. Except this time :(</sub>